# Install SSL with Nginx on Unbuntu (VPS server) - SSL: error: 0B080074: x509

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, https, vps

I've been blocking my site for HTTPS for 2 days now (VPS Server, Node.js, Nginx, Unbuntu).
I ordered a certificate from an organization, so I received 4 certificates.

From what I understood, I had to create a .key and .csr (which include my personal data) with this command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domainname_com.key -out domainname_com.csr
```

After that I had to bring together the 4 certificates in 1 alone (Because otherwise it does not work if I understood correctly), so that's what I did while respecting this order:

```
cat domainname.crt  intermediate1.crt  intermediate2.crt  root.crt > ssl-bundle.crt
```

Once the file was created (I checked the file by opening a text editor and everything is ok), I configured my default file (/ etc / nginx / site-available / default): that's ok.

And here is the problem, when I run I got an error: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file ("/ etc / ssl / private / example.key") failed (SSL: error: 0B080074: x509 certificate rout ...

After long research on the net, I saw that my keys did not correspond a priori, but I do not understand well how to solve this problem.

Thank you for your possible feedback, David

Comment: in case it is a public website why not use letsencrypt.?

Comment: Instead of telling us that the nginx config file is OK, why don't you add the relevant parts to your question?  It would probably help people answer your question.